# How do I make EC2 instances under the AWS account root user visible to IAM users?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have a small group of people using AWS services. 
When we first started, I mistakenly created EC2 instances under the root account, instead of creating them as an individual IAM user.

Now none of the IAM users can see those EC2 instances in the EC2 management portion of the AWS web console. The only way to see them is to log in as the AWS root account user.

Is there any way to make these EC2 instances visible to the IAM users?

AWS has documentation describing how to make instances visible to other accounts, but the same instructions don't seem to apply to this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The default policy for a IAM user is deny all services on AWS. So you have to provide appropriate permission for the IAM user.  Generate policy using this [website](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) or assign AWS managed policies to the user.
You can get the information about attaching a policy to an IAM user on the [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_manage.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a read-only group for EC2 instances by following these steps:

1. Create a new group which will have all read-only users for EC2
2. Select and attach the predefined policy `AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess` from the list when creating the new group
3. Put all the IAM users to this newly created group